# Ubuntu 17.04 LTS black screen after login after upgrade from 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, login, gui

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 17.04 LTS via the upgrade notification I received.

The computer boots up and I am shown the login screen with my existing account.

If I log in with the account in GUI mode, I get a black screen with desktop items (blinking those items when I click on the desktop screen). I can switch to a terminal and log in with the admin account, so the credentials are ok.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can get the GUI mode back for my account?

I am aware of all the commands and direct command line with ALT + CTRL + F1 but there is no upgrade required. All packages are fully updated.